# How to get total disc sectors in medium?

Tags: c#, sector, cd-rom

I would like to get the number of total sectors on a medium inserted in CD-ROM drive. Is there method for this in C#? I've checked the Management class in .NET but that does not seem to have a method.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API function `DeviceIoControl` will get that information for you.  Unfortunately, there's no simple wrapper for it in the .NET libraries.

[This sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363147(v=vs.85).aspx) shows how to do what you want in C.  Translating that to C# is non-trivial, but you might find some helpful pointers here:  [Calling DeviceIoControl from C# with IOCTL_DVD_* Control Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067216/calling-deviceiocontrol-from-c-with-ioctl-dvd-control-codes)

Comment: The example you are referring to uses Disk_Geometry structure, which returns only the used sectors on a disc, not a disc's total capacity. I need to learn the full capacity. How can I figure this out?

Comment: @Mert: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82993/windows-cd-burning-api.  The accepted answer has a C++ sample that uses the Image Mastering API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450(v=VS.85).aspx).  There's a sample of using it from C# at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx.

Comment: Unfortunately, that API only works when the disc is burnable. Otherwise, it throws an exception. There's gotta be an easy way to do this.